# Why does the icon in a button not adapt its size when the button is resized?

Tags: c#, windows, button, icons

I am new to C# and I'm making a C# .NET Framework Windows App Project.

I wanna make an add button but, when I change it's size the icon wont do the same!

[First it is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfRKC.png)
[Than it would become like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpGao.png)

I'm sorry if my grammar isn't so great!

I have tried to change the buttons size and I thought that the icon would change size but It didn't and now I have only a part of the icon

Comment: @Steve I suspect that OP is using the `Button.BackgroundImage` property to set the image, and the background is not set to Zoom or Stretch in `Button.BackgroundImageLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a Windows Forms App (WinForms). Buttons have a `BackgroundImageLayout` property you can set to `Zoom`; however, you will have to assign the image to the `BackgroundImage` property instead of the `Image` property for this to work.

You can also set `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Stretch` if you want to fill the button with the image and you don't mind a possible distortion of the image this involves.

If you have a `PictureBox`, you can assign the image to the `Image` property and set the `SizeMode` property instead. It has similar settings.

Answer (score -1):

In the button properties change BackgroundImageLayout to Stretch